# Deployed Spring Boot Application on Heroku Not working

Tags: firebase, spring-boot, heroku

I have my Spring Boot Application (Maven) which connects Firebase DB to fetch data and deployed on heroku. but i'm getting

> heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/check/value" host=.herokuapp.com request_id=4d200dd7-c893-4cc3-8ce2-a3a12bf79592 fwd="106.201.132.7" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https

and i found that issue with connecting firebaseDB by heroku(in my localserver, it is working).

Comment: This is the exception of the endpoint and not really helpful. We/you need the internal exception of the Spring Boot app to see what causes the problem.

Comment: This is what i'm getting in heroku logs. i found no exception other than this :(

Comment: Can't you login into the server and find the log file?

Comment: I did open the server and checked the log file. above log is what i found.